Only part of CSS works when parsed through a socket
Here is what my webpage looks like when I open it normally on my local machine.
Secondly, this is what my webpage looks like after I've sent the HTML and CSS files through a socket, with only part of the styling implemented. For reference, here is how I am loading these files to send to the client:
// accept connection from a client
Socket socket = server.accept();

// if connection is stable, read and write from client
try (OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream()) {
    InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
    var line = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in)).readLine();
    String file = line.substring(5, line.length() - 9);
    if (file.equals("")) {
        file = "index.html";
    } 
    
    // load script file from file directory
    StringBuilder contentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        BufferedReader webpage = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String str;
        while ((str = webpage.readLine()) != null) {
            contentBuilder.append(str);
        }
        webpage.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String content = contentBuilder.toString();

    // construct valid HTML response message
    final String CRLF = "\r\n"; // 13, 10
    String response = 
        "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" + CRLF + // status line: HTTP_VERSION RESPONSE_CODE RESPONSE_MESSAGE
        "Content-Length: " + content.getBytes().length + CRLF + // header
        CRLF + 
        content + 
        CRLF + CRLF;

    // write HTML message to the client
    out.write(response.getBytes());

Essentially, I read through all the contents of the HTML/CSS file and send it to the socket as a String.
I have printed out the full String objects collected by the BufferedReader and confirmed that the full contents of each file are being read and sent through to the client. Why would the styling only be partially communicated?
EDIT: It may be important to include how I'm using an additional stylesheet online for a font, i.e. I have this in my HTML:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">        
<link rel="stylesheet" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

EDIT 2: I tried changing the content length to be content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length but this unfortunately didn't change anything. I also tried adding CRLF.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length to the content length (as per a suggestion by Steffan) but this didn't work either.

Could be a difference in text encoding that makes content.getBytes() shorter than you expect. Can you try content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8) instead, and check what's the encoding on the browser side (Page Info)?

The content-length should cover the length of the body. Your content length covers content only, but the body you send is content + CRLF + CRLF. Apart from that browsers often require you to send the correct content-type - you don't send any. And you don't properly read the request but blindly assume that it will be completely within the first read, which isn't guaranteed. In general, HTTP/1 might look simple on the wire but it actually is not.  Study the standard for proper implementation if you really don't want to use existing libraries

@SteffenUllrich what libraries do you recommend for sending HTML and CSS files to an OutputStream?

This is not about sending HTML and CSS, its about properly implementing the HTTP protocol.

@BoppreH using view page source shows that the client is receiving the full CSS file... I'm quite lost as to why the styling does not come into effect then.

In addition to what Steffen says, you shouldn't be appending CRLF + CRLF to the end of any file at all.  The Content-Length should be just the byte size of the content and you should send only the headers and content by itself, don't do anything to add to the content (unless you are going to chunk or compress the response body, but that is outside the scope of the code shown).

Turns out when reading the CSS file I was reading line by line without adding a \n to the end of each line! So the CSS import was a big mess with certain lines being commented out!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
